# Getting equation (16.159) in Ashok Das' QFT textbook

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

I am having difficulty in getting equation (16.159), page 730, in the book "Lectures on Quantum Field Theory", 1st edition, by Ashok Das. (The equation and page number is slightly different in second edition). My attempt and the problem are described below.

We are considering electromagnetism in 1+1 dimensions. The fermions are massless. This model is known as Schwinger model. We are computing the amplitude associated to the following Feynman diagram

[image]

Its amplitude is given to be ( I don't think the precise form is relevant to my question):
$ I_5^{\mu \nu} = -e^2 \int \frac{d^2k}{(2 \pi )^2} \frac{ Tr\ \gamma_5 \gamma^\mu {\not} k \gamma^\nu ( {\not} k + {\not} p) }{k^2(k+p)^2} \tag{16.152}$

Then the author says that this amplitude is the Fourier transform of the matrix element (omitting time ordering symbols):
$$ \langle0| J^\mu_5 (x) A^\nu (0) |0\rangle .\tag{16.153} $$

So I guess this means, we can write:

$$ \langle0| J^\mu_5 (x) A^\nu (0) |0\rangle \ = \int \frac{d^2 p }{(2 \pi )^2 } e^{ipx} I^{\mu \nu}_5(p). \tag{A}$$

We hit with a derivative on both sides. The derivative acts only on the terms containing $x$:

$$ \langle0| \partial_\mu J^\mu_5 (x) A^\nu (0) |0\rangle \ = \int \frac{d^2 p }{(2 \pi )^2 } \partial_\mu e^{ipx} I^{\mu \nu}_5(p). \tag{B}$$

This brings down a $p_\mu$ on the right hand side:
$$ \langle0| \partial_\mu J^\mu_5 (x) A^\nu (0) |0\rangle \ = \int \frac{d^2 p }{(2 \pi )^2 }  e^{ipx} i p_\mu I^{\mu \nu}_5(p). \tag{C}$$

The values of $p_\mu I^{\mu \nu}_5 (p)$ is already calculated using dimensional regularization as
$$ p_\mu I^{\mu \nu}_5 (p) = - \frac{ie^2}{\pi} \epsilon^{\nu \mu} p_\mu .\tag{16.158}$$

Putting this in (C) gives:
$$ \langle0| \partial_\mu J^\mu_5 (x) A^\nu (0) |0\rangle \ = \int \frac{d^2 p }{(2 \pi )^2 }  e^{ipx} 
 \frac{e^2}{\pi} \epsilon^{\nu \mu} p_\mu. \tag{D}$$

Then comes the confusion. Author now says that this leads to the operator relation:
$$ \partial_\mu J^\mu_5 (x) =  \frac{e^2}{\pi} \epsilon_{\mu \nu} \partial^\mu A^\nu. \tag{16.159}$$

I don't see how to get (16.159) from (D). Basically how to move field A from left to right. Most likely I started with something incorrect to begin with but don't know what. Any hint will be appreciated.